# Closure of a connected set.

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces

If someone asks me why closure of a connected set is connected then what should i reply intuitively?
I don’t require a proof of this fact as i am already aware of the proof. I want to ask how to explain this to others intuitively that they get the idea?

Comment: Spaces don't have closures. Sets do.

Comment: Ivan i've edited the question. Thanks

Comment: You can answer that a connected set is made of one piece, there are no empty spaces between one part and the other. The closure points, also called adherent points, are stuck to the whole, which therefore remains all in one piece, that is connected if it was already.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose $\bar S$ is the union of 2 disjoint  pieces $A,\,B$ which are open in the sub-space $\bar S.$ Then $S$ is the union of 2 disjoint pieces $A\cap S, \,B \cap S$ which are open in the sub-space $S.$

So if $S$ is connected then wlog $A\cap S=S.$

The insight is that $A$ must be dense in $\bar S.$ So in the space $\bar S,$ the open set $B$ is disjoint from the dense set $A,$ which is not possible unless $B $ is empty.

That's as close to "intuitive" as I can get. The great 20th-century mathematician John von Neumann, when asked, by a student, about understanding, replied "Young man, in mathematics one does not understand things. One merely gets used to them."